# How do I update `ubuntu-themes`?

Tags: 13.10, gedit

I'm super annoyed by a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1242984) that has supposedly been fixed in "ubuntu-themes" but I am on 13.10 and I don't even see an "ubuntu-themes" package. Sooo... what package should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

> Sooo... what package should I be looking for?

You shouldn't looking for a package. As the bug (you linked) has been marked "Fix Released" that means, the fix has been released and you will get it immediately with an update. So, just update your system and it should be fine.

As for the ubuntu-themes package, I've looked and I've found that is a project that contains lot of other packages. [ubuntu-themes package in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes).

I don't think that it produces a single binary you can install, but this source package produces other binaries like : light-themes, ubuntu-artwork..etc . [See here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/13.04+13.10.20131014-0ubuntu1).

Answer (score 0):

- `ubuntu-themes` is a unified source package, to check for its packaged binaries run:

  ```
  grep -B7 "Source: ubuntu-themes" /var/lib/dpkg/available
  ```

  For Ubuntu Desktop they should be: *ubuntu-artwork*, *light-themes*, *ubuntu-mono*.
- The fix for ubuntu-themes has been pushed to Trusty. Seems there is no backport to Saucy. You try applying that patch on Saucy ubuntu-themes source.
- Gedit fixed upstream, so you may need to compile it from source.